# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking Issue in .NET

Tags: .net, e-commerce, analytics, tracking

Is there a difference in the ecommerce tracking script implemented in a .NET?

how to check is the script is working or not? The script is not recording any data when placed on the live site?

Does change in server affect tracking?

Currently I am using the following script -

```
`<script> 
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-X', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

       // Adding a Transaction
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id': transaction.id,
            'affiliation': '',
            'revenue': transaction.revenue,
            'shipping': transaction.shipping,
            'tax': transaction.tax,
            'currency': 'USD'  // local currency code.
        });

        // Adding Items
        $.each(transaction.AnalyticItems, function (i, data) {

            ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                'id': data.id,
                'name': data.name,
                'sku': data.sku,
                'category': data.category,
                'price': data.price,
                'quantity': data.quantity,
                'currency': 'USD' // local currency code.
            });

        });

        // Sending Data
        ga('ecommerce:send');

        ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

1. .NET is simply a server-side language producing front-end files (HTML, JS, etc.) for the client (i.e., browser) to display. So, in short, it doesn't change the way GA works whether it is a .NET app or a PHP site.
2. There are many good client-side debuggers or browser extension you can use to troubleshoot your GA implementation. There is the GA debugger if you are using GTM, Omnibug, etc. among many others. Check in your browser developer console and see if you are having javascript error, etc.
3. I'd suggest that you implement your GA with Google Tag Manager. It would probably make it easier to manage all the event tracking, etc. and provide better maintainability.